# How to get the value back from IN/OUT argument with nested activities

Tags: parameters, arguments, workflow-activity

Hi i have 2 nested activities. Both have parameters called 'SessionID'. Child activity have an IN/OUT argument called 'SessionIDParam'.

I set the SessionIDParam of the child from SessionID of the parent. In Child activity i set the SessionID of the child from SessionIDParam argument.

SessionID of the child changes during the execution of the child activity. At the end of the child i want the SessionID of the parent to be set to the new value of the SessionID of the child. I guessed the because that 'SessionIDParam' is set as 2 way i would be enough. But SessionID of the parent is not set.

What do i have to do other then that?

Thanks...

Comment: By the way, you'll need to ask questions that have a bit more context to get answers here – it's not clear what this question is about, or what language. It's worth tagging the language when asking, as many people follow tags they know about, so many more people will see the question. Have a couple of upvotes, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i solved my own problem :)

The was assignin new value to SessionID of the child. I was expecting that to change also SessionIDParam. When i reset SessionID of the child to SessionIDParam before the end of the activity, the IN/OUT parameter returned the value to parent activity and updated SessionID of the parent.

Thanks anyway...